# Website accessibility, Does text need to be accissible using Tab key?

Tags: accessibility

I have a website where I checked accessibility using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en chrome extension.

The doubt I have is, when I access the website using Tab it goes to all the interactive element of the page like Logo(with the link), Navigation with a link and other links and reads it properly but it does not go to the text content of the page or is not accessible using Tab key.

So can you please guide me on how it works and what all should be accessible using the Tab

TIA

Answer (score 2):

No only controls (links, inputs, buttons etc.) should be focusable. plain text should not be focusable.

The only exception to this rule is if you build a tab component, once you have selected a tab the next focus stop should be the container for the body text that is relevant to that tab (so you would need an element with `tabindex="0"` wrapped around the tab content in this rare case).

To access the text content of a page people will use the up and down arrows or the space bar to scroll the page.

For people who use a screen reader they have loads of other ways of accessing information on the page so you do not need to worry about whether they can focus text, that is what the screen reader does.

So to reiterate, as long as every interactive item (anything you can click and it performs an action, or anything you can enter information into) is focusable and can be activated with the keyboard (Enter or Space) you have done everything correctly.